# Limit step execution in a loop

Tags: bash, loops

I have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w dump.pcap -c 1500 &
    chromium-browser --app http://domain.com &
    sleep 60
    killall chromium-browser
    sudo killall tcpdump

    # do some stuff with pcap file
    # it basically converts the pcap to plain text using tshark
    # then a PHP script parses the plain text

    sleep 240
done
```

It works fine. But sometimes, for whatever reason, nothing is killed and the script gets stuck in that loop step. It is actually doing nothing, not taking any resource. It seems like the script is waiting for something to be killed.

I've tried limiting the packets captured by tcpdump, but it didn't work. tcpdump finishes its job normally, without having to be killed, but the script doesn't kill chromium and it doesn't proceed with the rest of the code.

Is there any way to detect if a step is taking too long and simply kill everything and move to the next step?

**Update**

**The `it is a long code`**

It converts the pcap file to plain text using tshark and a PHP script parses the plain text. The problem is not on this part because tshark is never called nor the PHP script. Everything stops before that.

**Increasing the sleep**

It does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: I hope, tcpdump & killall are within NOPASSWD section of /etc/sudoers line. Else, sudo might be waiting for the password.

Comment: @anishsane he says that the issue only occurs "sometimes", so I would imagine that isn't the issue.

Comment: Yes, exactly! sudo works on ticket basis (per tty). If the ticket expires or gets overwritten or so, it will just ask for password, as fail-safe.

Comment: Good point, but you would expect to see the prompt on stdout unless it have been redirected somewhere.

Comment: No, the password is never asked again. Plus, the script has managed to run non-stop for days and even for weeks without problems. It is just that "sometimes"...

Comment: I think the problem is as @anishsane says, sudo asking for a password. In this case, the `sudo tcpdump..` ..and it does not prompt on stdout because of the `&`

Comment: Do you have tcpdump in the NOPASSWD section of /etc/sudoers ? (I'm thinking about the sudo ticket expiring very close to those 60 + 240 secs)

Comment: Ticket isn't expiring. The script can run for days without problems.

Comment: I still strongly suspect of ticket timeout. The total sleep time in your script is 60+240=300 secs=5 mins. And default sudo timeout is 5 mins. So your script seems to be racing with that timeout (unless tcpdump is in the NOPASSWD section, or sudo timeout is greater than 5 mins: timestamp_timeout=X in sudo config)

Comment: also, it probably would be of help to see the script source for "# do some stuff with pcap file" ..maybe some `continue` that avoids that final `sleep 240` sometimes

Comment: @GermanGarcia So changing the initial sleep 60 to sleep 330 (or similar) should recreate the problem each time. Worth testing

Comment: @cmh yes, that would be a valuable test

Comment: I've updated the question. Plus, I've increased the password timeout to 30 to test it.

Comment: After thinking a little, what you guys say about the tickets may be playing a role on this issue. As the script has been running fine after the changes (I also changed the way the processes are killed), I think you guys should get a voteup for bringing up this possible cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind processes exiting non-gracefully you could use SIGKILL instead of SIGHUP:

```
killall -9 chromium-browser
sudo killall tcpdump
```

However in this case it is preferable to capture the pids of the processes you have started and only kill those (instead of killing all chromium-browers and tcpdump instances).

You can access the pid of the last run process with $!.

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w dump.pcap -c 1500 &
tcpdump_pid=$!
chromium-browser --app http://domain.com &
chromium-browser_pid=$!
sleep 60
kill -9 $tcpdump_pid
sudo kill $chromium-browser_pid
```

To answer your question of "Is there any way to detect if a step is taking too long and simply kill everything and move to the next step?" I would suggest using the `timeout` utility in coreutils.

```
timeout 5 sudo kill -9 $chromium-browser_pid
```

Although it would be advisable to determine why this is hanging, rather than work around it, else you will have a resource leak. It face it will be neater to rewrite your loop in terms of timeout:

```
sudo timeout 60 tcpdump -i eth0 -w dump.pcap -c 1500 &
timeout 60 chromium-browser --app http://domain.com &
```

Comment: I agree, killall can have dangerous side effects, because it just kills all matching processes. using `$!` is recommended wherever possible.

Comment: besides, you can simple give SIGINT to tcpdump. it handles SIGINT internally & exits _gracefully_.

Comment: @anishsane That's what you'd expect, but you can't guarantee any process will remain in a good, signal handling state (especially procs that interact with drivers).

Comment: ^^ Hmm... makes sense. possible, but it's the OS's responsibility, to send the signals properly. but, yes, a corner case may be possible, in which it would fail.

Comment: Broadly I agree with you, and question was asking about chromium so I have removed the SIGKILL from tcpdump

Comment: Chromium creates multiple processes even if you open only one window with only one tab. That's why I use killall. tcpdump isn't really an issue because if it is not killed, it finishes normally after reaching the limit of packets. I'll try your suggestions. Unfortunately, this is a situation that I can't reproduce whenever I want. I'll have to sit and wait to see if it works.

Comment: @rlcabral Those processes should be children of the process you start, so they should die when you kill the pid captured by `$!`.

Comment: I'll try that. But when I was testing the best way to kill chromium, for whatever reason the children were not killed and the chromium's window would stay open like it had crashed "Oh, snap... we are sorry" or whatever funny message it shows.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it makes some sense and it may help others with a similar problem. Although, as I also edited the `sudoers`, I can't be sure what exactly solved the problem. But your suggestion could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo tcpdump -Z root -w dump.pcap -n -i eth0 -G 300 -W 1
```

```
G - Timeout Seconds (After timeout period the comman gets killed automatically)

Z - drop root and runs as user privilege

W - Number files to be saved (as a splitted file)
```